# Problem accessing multidimensional array by key PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array that I need to loop to access all the arrays inside the second level array. The array comes from a request to an API.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
(
    [docGridArray] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [A] => pt_BR
                    [B] => en_US
                    [C] => pt_PT
                    [D] => es_MX
                    [E] => en_CA 
                )
        )

    [successCount] => 18
    [totalCount] => 18
)
1
)
```

The array that I need is docGridArray, but I wasn't able to access. I've tried many variations in a *foreach* loop, but mostly what I got it's ***Warning: Illegal string offset***

Here's what I tried so far:

```php
    //This one gives me the Illegal string offset
    foreach ((array)$response[0]['docGridArray'] as $item ){
          echo $item;
    }
    //This one works great
    foreach ((array)$response[0] as $item ){
          echo $item;
    }
    //This one gives me Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
    foreach ($response[0] as $item ){
          echo $item;
    }
```

I can't seem to access with the string key.

Comment: show result of  `var_export($response);`

Comment: Perhaps: `foreach ($response as $item) { echo $item['docGridArray'] }`

Answer (score 0):

The result is an object.

Try this and tell me if that work :

```
$you_array = json_decode(json_encode($api_result), true);    
foreach(array_column($your_array, "docGridArray") as $res){
        //your code
    }
```

Have fun :)

Comment: When I use json_decode returns null. I can't see a reason for this problem, makes no sense.

Comment: @LucasdeFreitasMiranda Did you encode into json before ? Else it's normal because your element is an object. Thus decoding as if it were json can't work;

Comment: I didn't, now I did, but when I try to use in array_column I get an error: Warning: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given.

Comment: @LucasdeFreitasMiranda, this error is legit because while `$your_array` isn't a real array this function won't work. Please run `var_dump(json_encode($res))` and give me the result.

Comment: var_dump returned: string(52440) ""Array\n(\n    [docGridArray] => Array\n        (\n            [0] => Array\n                (\n                    [docCodeLanguage] => pt_BR\n, the json_encode just added stuff. Maybe the API isn't returning the result the way it should...

Comment: @LucasdeFreitasMiranda What APi are you using ?

Comment: It's an internal API from where I work, just me and the creator are using. But I'm the only having problems.

Comment: @LucasdeFreitasMiranda Ok. According to me, the thing to do is converting this object to a multidimensional array. Did you try some object to array function ?

Comment: I didn't tried anything like this, any suggestions on kow to do that?

Comment: @LucasdeFreitasMiranda I found it on google : `function object_to_array($data)
{
    if (is_array($data) || is_object($data))
    {
        $result = array();
        foreach ($data as $key => $value)
        {
            $result[$key] = object_to_array($value);
        }
        return $result;
    }
    return $data;
}`

Comment: Apparently it's neither an array or an object, even if I encode and decode first. It fails the if condition.

Comment: I think a found the problem... the API returns me an invalid JSON, it's not a JSON structure, it's an array structure as a JSON. That's why when I decoded it returned NULL. I tested a dummy rest API and had no problems.

Comment: @LucasdeFreitasMiranda Yeah but to be sure your object is a valid json you have to encode it as : `json_encode($var)`. Thus you can use `json_decode()`

Comment: It's no go, I already tried that. The API should return me a valid JSON.

Comment: @LucasdeFreitasMiranda oh ok, since it's an internal API, maybe you can change it to have a good result ?

Answer (score 0):

you can access to the items in the  sub array docGridArray like this :

```
foreach ($response[0]['docGridArray'] as $item ){
      echo $item['docCodeLanguage']; 
}
```

as mentionned by @lucas you must decode your response before loop.

Comment: Please show difference with `//This one gives me the Illegal string offset
    foreach ((array)$response[0]['docGridArray'] as $item ){`

Comment: i execute this without casting the array and it works fine, i try it in phponline

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't access `$response[0]` directly, unless you are sure the endpoint will always return only 1 item.

You can do the job this example:

```
$response = [
    [
        'docGridArray' => [
            [
                    'docCodeLanguage' => 'pt_BR',
                    'docCommunity' => "something 1",
                    'docCommunityNoLink' => "something 2",
                    'docDomain' => "something 3",
                    'docExtIcon' => "something 4"
            ]
        ],
        'successCount' => 18,
        'totalCount' => 18,
    ]
];

foreach ($response as $item) {
    foreach($item['docGridArray'] as $document) {
        foreach($document as $key => $element) {
                echo $key . ' - ' . $element . "\n";    
        }
    }
}

/* will print:
docCodeLanguage - pt_BR
docCommunity - something 1
docCommunityNoLink - something 2
docDomain - something 3
docExtIcon - something 4
*/
```